# How can I use pyopencv_to function?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, embedding

I have a program written in python with OpenCV. I want to add a feature which is otsu thresholding with mask. So, I get a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041900/opencv-threshold-with-mask/33069436#33069436) written in c++. I tried to convert it as python, but it's too slow (because of python). Finally, I make up my mind to use c++ with python. I try to embedding, and I find pyopencv_to() function. But, I can't use it because of **PyArray_Check()**. When program entered this function, die immediately. It doesn't give any error message. I guess it may be segmentation fault. Many stack overflow's answers says that "use import_array()". But it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code.

convert.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "numpy/ndarrayobject.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "convert.hpp"

static PyObject* opencv_error = 0;

static int failmsg(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char str[1000];

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, str);
    return 0;
}

class PyAllowThreads
{
public:
    PyAllowThreads() : _state(PyEval_SaveThread()) {}
    ~PyAllowThreads()
    {
        PyEval_RestoreThread(_state);
    }
private:
    PyThreadState* _state;
};

class PyEnsureGIL
{
public:
    PyEnsureGIL() : _state(PyGILState_Ensure()) {}
    ~PyEnsureGIL()
    {
        PyGILState_Release(_state);
    }
private:
    PyGILState_STATE _state;
};

#define ERRWRAP2(expr) \
try \
{ \
    PyAllowThreads allowThreads; \
    expr; \
} \
catch (const cv::Exception &e) \
{ \
    PyErr_SetString(opencv_error, e.what()); \
    return 0; \
}

using namespace cv;

static PyObject* failmsgp(const char *fmt, ...)
{
char str[1000];

va_list ap;
va_start(ap, fmt);
vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), fmt, ap);
va_end(ap);

PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, str);
return 0;
}

static size_t REFCOUNT_OFFSET = (size_t)&(((PyObject*)0)->ob_refcnt) +
    (0x12345678 != *(const size_t*)"\x78\x56\x34\x12\0\0\0\0\0")*sizeof(int);

static inline PyObject* pyObjectFromRefcount(const int* refcount)
{
    return (PyObject*)((size_t)refcount - REFCOUNT_OFFSET);
}

static inline int* refcountFromPyObject(const PyObject* obj)
{
    return (int*)((size_t)obj + REFCOUNT_OFFSET);
}

class NumpyAllocator : public MatAllocator
{
public:
    NumpyAllocator() {}
    ~NumpyAllocator() {}

    void allocate(int dims, const int* sizes, int type, int*& refcount,
                uchar*& datastart, uchar*& data, size_t* step)
    {
        PyEnsureGIL gil;

        int depth = CV_MAT_DEPTH(type);
        int cn = CV_MAT_CN(type);
        const int f = (int)(sizeof(size_t)/8);
        int typenum = depth == CV_8U ? NPY_UBYTE : depth == CV_8S ? NPY_BYTE :
                    depth == CV_16U ? NPY_USHORT : depth == CV_16S ? NPY_SHORT :
                    depth == CV_32S ? NPY_INT : depth == CV_32F ? NPY_FLOAT :
                    depth == CV_64F ? NPY_DOUBLE : f*NPY_ULONGLONG + (f^1)*NPY_UINT;
        int i;
        npy_intp _sizes[CV_MAX_DIM+1];
        for( i = 0; i < dims; i++ )
            _sizes[i] = sizes[i];
        if( cn > 1 )
        {
            /*if( _sizes[dims-1] == 1 )
                _sizes[dims-1] = cn;
            else*/
                _sizes[dims++] = cn;
        }
        PyObject* o = PyArray_SimpleNew(dims, _sizes, typenum);
        if(!o)
            CV_Error_(CV_StsError, ("The numpy array of typenum=%d, ndims=%d can not be created", typenum, dims));
        refcount = refcountFromPyObject(o);
        npy_intp* _strides = PyArray_STRIDES(o);
        for( i = 0; i < dims - (cn > 1); i++ )
            step[i] = (size_t)_strides[i];
        datastart = data = (uchar*)PyArray_DATA(o);
    }

    void deallocate(int* refcount, uchar*, uchar*)
    {
        PyEnsureGIL gil;
        if( !refcount )
            return;
        PyObject* o = pyObjectFromRefcount(refcount);
        Py_INCREF(o);
        Py_DECREF(o);
    }
};

NumpyAllocator g_numpyAllocator;

enum { ARG_NONE = 0, ARG_MAT = 1, ARG_SCALAR = 2 };

int init_numpy() {
    import_array();
    return 0;
}

const static int numpy_initialized = init_numpy();

int pyopencv_to(const PyObject* o, Mat& m, const char* name, bool allowND)
{
    if(!o || o == Py_None)
    {
        if( !m.data )
            m.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;
        return true;
    }

    if( !PyArray_Check(o) )    // this line makes error without message
    {
        failmsg("%s is not a numpy array", name);
        return false;
    }

    // NPY_LONG (64 bit) is converted to CV_32S (32 bit)
    int typenum = PyArray_TYPE(o);
    int type = typenum == NPY_UBYTE ? CV_8U : typenum == NPY_BYTE ? CV_8S :
        typenum == NPY_USHORT ? CV_16U : typenum == NPY_SHORT ? CV_16S :
        typenum == NPY_INT || typenum == NPY_LONG ? CV_32S :
        typenum == NPY_FLOAT ? CV_32F :
        typenum == NPY_DOUBLE ? CV_64F : -1;

    if( type < 0 )
    {
        failmsg("%s data type = %d is not supported", name, typenum);
        return false;
    }

    int ndims = PyArray_NDIM(o);
    if(ndims >= CV_MAX_DIM)
    {
        failmsg("%s dimensionality (=%d) is too high", name, ndims);
        return false;
    }

    int size[CV_MAX_DIM+1];
    size_t step[CV_MAX_DIM+1], elemsize = CV_ELEM_SIZE1(type);
    const npy_intp* _sizes = PyArray_DIMS(o);
    const npy_intp* _strides = PyArray_STRIDES(o);
    bool transposed = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < ndims; i++)
    {
        size[i] = (int)_sizes[i];
        step[i] = (size_t)_strides[i];
    }

    if( ndims == 0 || step[ndims-1] > elemsize ) {
        size[ndims] = 1;
        step[ndims] = elemsize;
        ndims++;
    }

    if( ndims >= 2 && step[0] < step[1] )
    {
        std::swap(size[0], size[1]);
        std::swap(step[0], step[1]);
        transposed = true;
    }

    if( ndims == 3 && size[2] <= CV_CN_MAX && step[1] == elemsize*size[2] )
    {
        ndims--;
        type |= CV_MAKETYPE(0, size[2]);
    }

    if( ndims > 2 && !allowND )
    {
        failmsg("%s has more than 2 dimensions", name);
        return false;
    }

    m = cv::Mat(ndims, size, type, PyArray_DATA(o), step);

    if( m.data )
    {
        m.u->refcount = *refcountFromPyObject(o);
        m.addref(); // protect the original numpy array from deallocation
        // (since Mat destructor will decrement the reference counter)
    };
    m.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;

    if( transposed )
    {
        cv::Mat tmp;
        tmp.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;
        transpose(m, tmp);
        m = tmp;
    }
    return true;
}

PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat& m)
{
    if( !m.data )
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    Mat temp, *p = (Mat*)&m;
    if(!(p->u->refcount) || p->allocator != &g_numpyAllocator)
    {
        temp.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;
        ERRWRAP2(m.copyTo(temp));
        p = &temp;
    }
    p->addref();
    return pyObjectFromRefcount(&(p->u->refcount));
}
```

threshold.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "convert.hpp"
#include "numpy/ndarrayobject.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

double otsu_8u_with_mask(const Mat1b src, const Mat1b& mask)
{
    const int N = 256;
    int M = 0;
    int i, j, h[N] = { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
    {
        const uchar* psrc = src.ptr(i);
        const uchar* pmask = mask.ptr(i);
        for (j = 0; j < src.cols; j++)
        {
            if (pmask[j])
            {
                h[psrc[j]]++;
                ++M;
            }
        }
    }

    double mu = 0, scale = 1. / (M);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        mu += i * (double)h[i];

    mu *= scale;
    double mu1 = 0, q1 = 0;
    double max_sigma = 0, max_val = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        double p_i, q2, mu2, sigma;

        p_i = h[i] * scale;
        mu1 *= q1;
        q1 += p_i;
        q2 = 1. - q1;

        if (std::min(q1, q2) < FLT_EPSILON || std::max(q1, q2) > 1. - FLT_EPSILON)
            continue;

        mu1 = (mu1 + i * p_i) / q1;
        mu2 = (mu - q1 * mu1) / q2;
        sigma = q1 * q2*(mu1 - mu2)*(mu1 - mu2);
        if (sigma > max_sigma)
        {
            max_sigma = sigma;
            max_val = i;
        }
    }

    return max_val;
}

static PyObject * otsu_with_mask(PyObject *self, PyObject * args) {
    PyObject pySrc, pyMask;
    Mat src, mask;

    import_array();

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &pySrc, &pyMask))
        return NULL;

    pyopencv_to(&pySrc, src, "source");
    pyopencv_to(&pyMask, mask, "mask");

    double thresh = otsu_8u_with_mask(src, mask);

    return Py_BuildValue("i", thresh);
}

static PyMethodDef ThresholdMethods[] = {
    {"otsu_with_mask", otsu_with_mask, METH_VARARGS, "Otsu thresholding with mask."},
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef thresholdModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "customThreshold",
    "Thresholding module.",
    -1,
    ThresholdMethods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_customThreshold(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&thresholdModule);
}
```

convert.hpp

```
#ifndef __CONVERT_HPP__
#define __CONVERT_HPP__

#include <Python.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int pyopencv_to(const PyObject* o, Mat& m, const char* name = "<unknown>", bool allowND=true);
PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat& m);

#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do you choose to use C++ with Python wrap to do this simple task? I think you could achieve the same result easily using Python only...?

I assume you want to use adaptive thresholding method in OpenCV.

First of all, you can compute the adaptive threshold value of the input gray image. The value can be computed by the following function:

```
def compute_otsu_value(im_gray):
    hist = cv2.calcHist([im_gray], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    hist_norm = hist.ravel() / hist.max()
    cum_sum_mat = hist_norm.cumsum()
    fn_min = np.inf
    thresh = -1
    for i in xrange(1, 256):
        p1, p2 = np.hsplit(hist_norm, [i])
        q1, q2 = cum_sum_mat[i], cum_sum_mat[255] - cum_sum_mat[i]
        if q1 == 0 or q2 == 0:
            continue
        b1, b2 = np.hsplit(np.arange(256), [i])
        m1, m2 = np.sum(p1 * b1) / q1, np.sum(p2 * b2) / q2
        v1, v2 = np.sum(((b1-m1)**2)*p1)/q1, np.sum(((b2-m2)**2)*p2)/q2
        fn = v1 * q1 + v2 * q2
        if fn < fn_min:
            fn_min = fn
            thresh = i
    return thresh
```

Finally, in the main() function, you can load the input image as a gray image, and get the threshold image accordingly.

```
im_gray = cv2.imread("input.png", 0)
otsu_value = comput_otsu_values(im_gray)
im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, otsu_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Howard. But I have to compute lots of frame not only otsu thresholding but another things in realtime. For realtime image processing, Python is too slow. (I already implement it as python, but it show me 3fps...) The UI already developed in Python, so I don't have any choice except wrapping. It is my mind. Do you have any good idea of this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any better ideas. A real-time solution always requires to take extra steps ... Good luck!

Comment: @Harine Anecdotally, you could try a faster Python interpreter, such as [PyPy](https://pypy.org/), though it may not support all the features you need, be truly faster, or fast enough for your case..