# Otsu thresholding inside mask

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, masking

I'm working with Python and trying to do Otsu thresholding on an image but only inside the mask (yes, I have an image and a mask image). It means less pixel on the image will be included in the histogram for calculating the Otsu threshold.

I'm currently using the `cv2.threshold` function without the mask image and have no idea how to do this kind of job.

```py
ret, OtsuMat = cv2.threshold(GaborMat, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Since this function also incorporates the pixels outside the mask, I think it will give a less accurate threshold.

This is the example of the image and its mask:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p8JMhncJs19oOWO9RdkWuEADVGqE-gzQ?usp=sharing

Hope there is a OpenCV or other lib function to do it easily (and also with fast computing), but any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: For OpenCV, it seems there's no in-built function for that. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33069436/11089932) suggests (C++ instead of Python), you can set up an own function for this recycling the OpenCV source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a try at this using the `threshold_otsu()` method from **skimage** and a Numpy masked array. I don't know if there are faster ways - the **skimage** is normally pretty well optimised. If anyone else wants to take my sample data and try other ideas on it, please feel free - although there is a service charge of one upvote ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

# Set up some repeatable test data, 4 blocks 100x100 pixels each of random normal np.uint8s centred on 32, 64, 160,192
np.random.seed(42)
a=np.random.normal(size = (100,100), loc = 32,scale=10).astype(np.uint8)
b=np.random.normal(size = (100,100), loc = 64,scale=10).astype(np.uint8)
c=np.random.normal(size = (100,100), loc = 160,scale=10).astype(np.uint8)
d=np.random.normal(size = (100,100), loc = 192,scale=10).astype(np.uint8)
# Stack (concatenate) the 4 squares horizontally across the page
im = np.hstack((a,b,c,d))
# Next line is just for debug
cv2.imwrite('start.png',im)
```

That gives us this:

[image]

```
# Now make a mask revealing only left half of image, centred on 32 and 64
mask=np.zeros((100,400))
mask[:,200:]=1
masked = ma.masked_array(im,mask)
print(threshold_otsu(masked.compressed()))       # Prints 47

# Now do same revealing only right half of image, centred on 160 and 192
masked = ma.masked_array(im,1-mask)
print(threshold_otsu(masked.compressed()))       # Prints 175
```

The histogram of the test data looks like this, x-axis is 0..255

[image]

---

Adapting to your own sample data, I get this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

# Load images
im   = cv2.imread('eye.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
mask = cv2.imread('mask.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# Calculate Otsu threshold on entire image
print(threshold_otsu(im))                       # prints 130

# Now do same for masked image
masked = ma.masked_array(im,mask>0)
print(threshold_otsu(masked.compressed())).     # prints 124
```

Comment: Glad it works for you. Remember that questions, and answers, are free, so come back and ask some more if you get stuck.  Good luck with your project!