# OpenCV Otsu's Thresholding: Calculate single threshold value for multiple Mat objects

Tags: c++, opencv

I have multiple 1-dimensional `Mat` objects (lines) of different lengths all extracted from the same image which need to be thresholded to binary.
In order to achieve a more "global" thresholding value, i want to use Otsu's thresholding on all of the lines at the same time.

My current approach is to use `vconcat` to obtain a single `Mat` object.
As all rows and cols of a `Mat` have the same length, i would expect the non-initialized values to be set to 0 like this:

```
[234, 200, 123, 165, 91, 27, 142, 211,
  21, 231, 100,  99, 87, 23,   0,   0,
  234, 200, 123,  0,  0,  0,   0,   0,
  234, 200, 123,  34,132, 32, 242,  12]
```

Of course, i don't want the `0`'s to influence the calculation of the treshold value.
Any suggestions on how to approach this problem in an efficient/ elegant way?

Comment: Use `hconcat `. But save before length of each row and order of this rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me (Windows 10, OpenCV 4.1.1, Visual Studio Community 2017), the following works like a charm:

```cpp
// Set up example matrices.
cv::Mat A = (cv::Mat_<uint8_t>(1, 8) << 234, 200, 123, 165, 91, 27, 142, 211);
cv::Mat B = (cv::Mat_<uint8_t>(1, 6) << 21, 231, 100, 99, 87, 23);
cv::Mat C = (cv::Mat_<uint8_t>(1, 3) << 234, 200, 123);
cv::Mat D = (cv::Mat_<uint8_t>(1, 8) << 234, 200, 123, 34, 132, 32, 242, 12);   

// Generate intermediate matrix.
cv::Mat inter;
cv::hconcat(std::vector<cv::Mat>{ A, B, C, D }, inter);

// Calculate Otsu's threshold.
cv::Mat thr;
double otsu = cv::threshold(inter, thr, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);
```

The initialized matrices `A`, `B`, ... have different lengths. The intermediate matrix `inter` generated by [`cv::hconcat`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4676b1376cdc4e528dab6bd9edc51c1a) has (correct) length 25, and no additional `0` elements. The resulting threshold `otsu` by Otsu's method is 142. If I manually add the additional `0` elements from your example in the initialization, I actually get a threshold of 100.

Maybe, you can provide your actual code to compare what's different!? Maybe, the behavior of `hconcat` is not as expected or documented!?

Nevertheless, hopefully this will help you!

Comment: oh i think i was confusing hconcat and vconcat... ;))) my idea was to generate a 2D-Mat using the concatenation methods. But concatenating to a 1D-Mat and separating the lines afterwards is actually not a bad idea since this way the whole problem is eliminated

Comment: Would you know an elegant way of retrieving the thresholded Mats _A, B, C, D_ in your example? If not, nevermind, because im sure i could figure out something that works (like saving the length and first element's position of each Mat in _thr_

Comment: @CommodoreYournero Apart from what you've already mentioned, no, I can't think of a nice solution, since there's no "connection" between `A`, `B`, ... and `inter` like you get when generating ROIs from a Mat. Also, using Mat pointers seems not to work here. A complete different approach would be to generate a "threshold mask", and implement an own "masked" `threshold` method like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041900).

Comment: Interesting approach, although i will try the easy way for now. Might be quite useful for some other stuff though, too! I'll accept this answer as i can do the rest on my own